# Gui wallet seed imported into mymonero web wallet.Any possible security risks?

Tags: security

I have a mymonero web wallet that has some moneros in it
I recently downloaded the new GUI wallet and sent some monero to it from exchanges.
The other day I went to the web wallet but I put in my seed from the GUI by mistake.
Not really knowing what I was doing I imported the GUI wallet into the web wallet.
The GUI wallet still has the same amount that I put in it,but it shows up in the
web wallet when I type that seed into it as well.
When I type the original seed from the original web wallet the proper amount shows up for my first wallet.

How do I delete the web wallet with GUI seed?

Is it necessary?
Does this impose any kind of security risk?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Not really a security risk unless some powerful criminal organization has specifically targeted you.

You don't need to delete anything. Simply create a new wallet with your GUI and send the balance of the mistaken GUI wallet entered into myMonero, to your new GUI wallet. To make a new wallet just press "cancel" when the GUI asks for wallet password. That way the mistaken wallet's balance will be zero and you simply don't use it anymore. Once you are sure the balance is zero, delete your mnemonic seed so you don't get confused.

Your new GUI wallet will now have the funds you wanted in your GUI and will have no connection to myMonero.

Answer (score 2):

It's safe in principle, but. Every time you access the page, your browser downloads the source code of the page again. If an attacker intercepts this he could change the code to steal your mnemonic. A malware extension in your browser could do the same. So, consider that you've exposed your mnemonic to this risk - it doesn't mean that something was going on, but it **could** have.

If you're going to use mymonero, it's advised to get the mymonero [chrome extension](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5fybe7/mymonero_is_now_available_as_a_chrome_extension/). This is the same code of the page but packed and isolated from other extensions so you're not downloading the page again but are sure to be always using the same code running in your browser. It's much safer then just accessing the web page.

I'd advise you to create a new GUI wallet, and move majority your monero there. The web-wallet could stil be used for smaller amouts.